# How to create conflict in micro fiction which force reader to interact

Tags: fiction, social-media, flash-fiction, reader-engagement

Are there some specific rule of thumb or heuristic to consider while writing a micro fiction or a 500 word post on some social media to create conflict or anything which force reader to interact or comment about the post or story?

**Edit**
I think my question was not clear. I want to elaborate it. According to @wetcircuit comment, [Clickbait](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45317/the-art-of-clickbait-captions) Question is a good example. But my question is once user had clicked on my story with a strong clickbait caption or something, How to make some interaction baits in to a story line. Like to touch some social trend and/or using a community specific sensitive issue which force reader to be agree or to disagree.(I guess being disagree make them more willing to comment) Or to leave some loop hole in the story which user quickly identify and point out in comment which make them think they are wiser or writer is some fool or like they are helping writer to gain attention.

Normally if we write some normal Good work of micro or flash fiction user only give likes or just scroll ahead. It doesn't make them to deep dive and take their time to comment on post. Just like click-baits, some kind of interaction-baits are necessary to engage readers. We find these kind of examples in some YouTube Videos and/or some kind of News articles but Are there some examples for stories as well?

Comment: possibly related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45317/the-art-of-clickbait-captions

Comment: @wetcircuit Thanks. Yeah very much something similar. I will edit my question on behalf of your comment. It really helps to elaborate and provide more proper words for my question to rephrase.

Comment: I can understand that you want people to engage with your work - take it from me, it's disheartening when you put weeks of effort into writing something and nobody comments on it - but writing a deliberate plot hole with the intent of making people comment about how stupid you apparently are is a terrible idea on every level. Is there any reason you're so desperate for comments that you'd be willing to resort to that?

Comment: @F1Krazy no it is not about being desperate, and leaving a loop hole is just asking for idea to clarify my intention. Actually making people engaged is for every kind of creative writing work. Like if I am creating a story I just don't want people to read and just praise and move on. I want them to think and to feel need to talk about it. Because I consider this as merit of success to be word of mouth. Not just being praised by people but also being word of mouth. So just looking for some examples or good practices to keep in mind while writing. And also it sometimes the need of client as well

Comment: And why it even sound desperate? Isn't it the same thing like using human physiology like we do in clickbaits. And the game designer used to make their game addictive. So why can't a writer make his writing engaging. Its just a different goal from making story like able to making it comentable.

Answer (score 1):

While clickbait are psychological tricks that are good but very well known nowadays, one option should be to take a strong position on one important topic that make people debate or disagree strongly.

As a caricature I would give the example of any Tweet with Trump is this or that will trigger many reactions.

Otherwise for me the way to do this in a professional way is to practice [Copywriting](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-copywriting-course/).